# Reading and Writing CMYK TIFF in Java 9

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-9, javax.imageio

My goal here is to read in a CMYK Tiff image, mess with the pixels and then write out a new CMYK Tiff image. I am having a tough time finding any kind of example for this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Originally, I was doing this with RGB JPEG images without a problem using code like this:

```
// read input image
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(inputJPGAsFile);

// made output image that is same size as input image
FinalImage = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// mess with pixels in output image

// write as JPG
ImageIO.write(FinalImage, "JPEG", outputJPGAsFile);
```

However, now I am trying to figure out how to change this to work with CMYK Tiffs. It doesn't seem like there is a type for BufferedImage that would be anything like "TYPE_INT_CMYK". So then I was trying to use the ColorModel of the input image, but this crashes with the following error `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color space`. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
// read input image
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(inputTiffAsFile);

// get the CMYK color space of input image
ColorModel colorModel = in.getColorModel();
BufferedImage FinalImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(100, 100), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

// Copy in to FinalImage with some pixel manipulation

// write final image
ImageIO.write(FinalImage, "TIFF", outputTiffAsFile);
```

Also, I put java 9 because that is what I have been using, but I can upgrade to a newer version if that makes things easier. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might need JAI but its along time I read tiff

Comment: Did you try this in a stand-alone Java application, without JavaFX being involved?

Comment: @gpasch Java 9 and later has a TIFF plugin (the non-native one from JAI) bundled as default.

Comment: Can you please add the full stack trace of your exception? And indicate what line in your code that corresponds to?